# Why is the state of a promise 'pending' if logged out during executing it's handler?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

This question might not be about a practical issue, although I'm still curious what is happening here:

```
const r = Promise.resolve('I resolved')
  .then(() => {
    console.log('*****then*****')
    console.log( r )
    console.log('*****then*****')
  })

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('*****setTimeout*****')
  console.log( r )
  console.log('*****setTimeout*****')
})

/*
logs:
*****then*****
Promise { <pending> }
*****then*****

*****setTimeout*****
Promise { undefined }
*****setTimeout*****
*/
```

In the .then handler I purposefully don't want to log out the result that I got from the resolved promise, which would be a typical use case, I'm curious about the actual value of the promise itself.

Here's what I think is happening: r is not the value of Promise.resolve(), as .then returns a new promise. If I log out the value in the Timers phase, it's after the .then handler finished, so it logs out a promise resolved to 'undefined' as there was nothing explicitly returned.

But why is the value of r still pending in the .then handler? Is it because that the .then handler hasn't finished executing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because that the .then handler hasn't finished executing?

Yes. The `r` promise will be resolved with the return value of that callback function, so it can't be fulfilled before it has finished executing and therefore must be still pending.

Answer (score 0):

**This is what you want.**

You don't pass the resolved value to the .then() function. Or return it. When returning a promise. You need an async function with await. Await evaluates the promise and extracts the value.

```
  (async function () {
    const r = await Promise.resolve("I resolved")
      .then((r) => {
        console.log("*****then*****");
        console.log(r);
        console.log("*****then*****");
        return {
          r,
          text: "this works",
          remember: "use async/await to resolve promises",
        };
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("*****setTimeout*****");
      console.log(r.r, r.text, r.remember);
      console.log("*****setTimeout*****");
    }, 1000);
  })();
```